# To generate a random bit pattern with certain constraints

Tags: c, random

I want to generate a random stream of 0's & 1's (10000 iteration) under the constraint that 1 should occur only one out of 400 iteration .Can anyone help me out with it's C code and the libraries and the functions to be used in C.

Comment: I've added the random tag. There could be better ways than mine that will give better statistical properties for such an asymmetric Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Do you want `0` to occur exactly 399 times as often as `1` or do you want the probability for `0` to be 399 times the probability to get a `1`?

Answer (score 1):

`400.0 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) < 1 ? 1 : 0` is one way.

Drop the ternary if you're feeling confident and the expression matches the lvalue type. Note the careful placement of `400.0` and `1.0`.

(**Important note**: don't accept this solution if you need an accurate 1 in 400 probability. This solution will not work well if RAND_MAX is a "very poor multiple" of 400. Given that the standard mandates RAND_MAX to be no lower than 32767, at that low value the statistical properties of this technique would be poor.)

Comment: [`rand()` considered harmfull](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY) also explains why this solution is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that picks one hit out of an interval of 400 in advance and reports it if its turn comes; otherwise it emits a 0. When the hit is reported, the hit for the next interval is determined with `rand()`. The functon keeps its state with `static` variables and uses the special value -1 to initialise itself:

```
int pick(int n)
{
    return 400 * rand() / ((double) RAND_MAX + 1);
}

int next()
{
    static int hit = -1;
    static int count;

    if (hit < 0) hit = pick(WIDTH);
    if (count++ == hit) {
        hit = ((hit / WIDTH) + 1) * WIDTH + pick(WIDTH);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    printf("%8d %d\n", i, next());
}
```

This is different from Bathsheba's solution, because it guarantees a distribution of 1:399 if your sample is a multiple of 400. This means it might not be what you're looking for.

**Edit** I've introduced a new function `pick` that picks a random number between 0 (includive) and `n` (exclusive), which hopefully provides a better distribution than the modulo function.

Comment: No. No. No. rand() % N is the cause of so many problems in this world! It introduces a statistical bias if the generator's periodicity is not a multiple of N.

Comment: ;-) Although I'd hate to see `rand() %` anywhere in a missile guidance system.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Anyway, overstated as it might be, I've taken your point.